# Unbounded Knapsack and Classical Knapsack Comparison

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have read two distinct problem **0-1 Knapsack Problem** and **Unbounded Knapsack Problem** on the internet. I found that these two problems are both solved by Dynamic Programming but in two different way.
If **0-1 Knapsack Problem** is solved by using two dimension array, **Unbounded Knapsack Problem** only utilizes one dimension array.

You can read more [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem) and [Unbounded Knapsak Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm)

The difference in these two problem, as I know, is that the **0-1 Knapsack Problem** only contains the limited amount of things, while **Unbounded Knapsack Problem** enables to take 1 or more instances of any resource. However, I do not know why it changes the way to solve this problem? Can you give me the reason for this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am sorry but my question is the last sentence, I only miss the question mark here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table approach is simpler to explain and debug, that is why algorithm decriptions usually show such way.

Note that for 0-1 Knapsack Problem we must exclude possibility to reuse item twice. So at every step of outer loop we update previous best results using current item.

But we use only the last row of table (look at indices `i` and `i-1`), so we can diminish table size to `2 x Capacity` using only current and last rows.

Moreover, we can use approach with one-dimensional array, applying a trick - to avoid reusing item, we can perform traversal in backward direction.

Python code below uses data from wiki page and shows both table and linear array implementations.

```
wt = [23,26,20,18,32,27,29,26,30,27]
val = [505,352,458,220,354,414,498,545,473,543]

def knap1(w,v, cap):
    n = len(w)
    m = [[0]*(cap+1) for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(cap + 1):
            if w[i] > j:
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j]
            else:
                m[i][j] = max(m[i-1][j], m[i-1][j-w[i]] + v[i])
    return m[n-1][cap]

def knap2(w,v, cap):
    n = len(w)
    m = [0]*(cap+1)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(cap, w[i]-1,-1):
                m[j] = max(m[j], m[j-w[i]] + v[i])
    return m[cap]


print(knap1(wt, val, 67))
print(knap2(wt, val, 67))

>>1270
>>1270
```

Comment: I am sorry but If I apply 2D table for solving the Unbounded Knapsack, will I take the same solution? And I don't know why but It is so amazing that your two algorithms give the same result, in what case does it happen?

Comment: For unbounded knapsack you need to modify table algorithm - for example, choose maximum using not only `m[i-1][j-w[i]]+ v[i]` cell but also `m[i-1][j-2*w[i]]+ 2*v[i]` and so on, using up to `j/w[i]` items. Algorithm becomes more complex slower, so one-dimension algorithm is much better. My two implementation give the same result because they essentialy represent the same solution scheme. `Best results for items 0..i = > update using item i+1 choosing for ever weight max(m[j], m[j-w[i]] + v[i])` and so on

Comment: @Alex W There is no need to check `w[i]<=j` because range of for loop provides this.

Comment: @MBo thanks -- I should have read the range of the inner loop more carefully.